# connection to a monitor display without detection

Tags: windows-10, mac, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display

Is it possible to connect my laptop to a monitor through HDMI without it being detected on the laptop and just mirror the content? Maybe through a HDMI splitter or something ? I'm setting up a lie detection experiment (post covid) and will project subject answers on to a screen to a group then ask further questions to detect truth and lies but don't want it obvious it's on an extended display which could be viewed from display settings on the laptop. I thought maybe a splitter might do this. I think it was possible back in the days of VGA but I know that was an analog signal and HDMI is digital if that has anything to do with it. I know there are programs that could probably achieve this but I'm not very tech savvy and don't want to pay for subscriptions when cables might do the trick Thanks for any help